# RxAndroid: onCompleted not being called

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm using rx libraries im my app to call some REST api on my server and to show the results on screen.
I'm also following the MVP design pattern. So I have a Presenter and an Interactor classes.
In MainInteractor.java I have the following method:

```
public Observable<Card> fetchCard(final String clientId, final CardFetchedListener listener) {
        Log.i(TAG, "FetchCard method");

        // Manipulate the observer
        return CARDS
                .doOnCompleted(new Action0() {
                    @Override
                    public void call() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "CARDS Completed");
                    }
                })
                .flatMap(new Func1<Card, Observable<Card>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<Card> call(final Card card) {

                        return ResourceClient.getInstance(card)
                                .getIDCard()
                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                .doOnError(new Action1<Throwable>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                                        Log.w(TAG, "interactor -> fetchCard 2", throwable);
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                                .flatMap(new Func1<CardMeta, Observable<Card>>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public Observable<Card> call(CardMeta cardMeta) {
                                        card.setCardMeta(cardMeta);
                                        saveOrUpdateCardToTheDb(card);
                                        return Observable.just(card);
                                    }
                                })
                                .doOnCompleted(new Action0() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void call() {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "Completed body");
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                });
    }
```

In the logs I can see the "Completed Body" string.

The above method is being called by MainPresenter.java class as follows:

```
interactor.fetchCard(clientId, this)
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Observer<Card>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted() {
                            Log.i(TAG, "fetchCard onCompleted");
                            view.hideProgressDialog();
                            view.updateCardsAdapter(cards);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Fetch Card error ", e);
                            onFailure(parseThrowable(e));
                        }


                        @Override
                        public void onNext(Card card) {
                            if (card != null) {
                                Log.i(TAG, card.getTenant() + " was fetched and will be displayed");
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

The problem is that the onCompleted method in the Presenter class is never bein called. I have tried to call onCompleted myself and it worked, but the problem is I don't know actually when the observable has finished emitting cards.

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

CARDS is also an observable that contains meta info. It is initialized using

```
Observable.from(tenants)
.filter(...).flatMap(// I'm using create operator here and it is calling its onCompleted method successflly);
```

Comment: Please mor code "CARDS"

Comment: @quangminhs updated

Comment: Please try Observable.from(tenants)
.filter(...).flatMap().doOnComplete(() -> Log.e("TAG", "On doOnComplete"));

Comment: @quangminhs Yes I can see the message in logs

Comment: Perhaps CARDS never completes? Can you provide more context?

Comment: @MaximVolgin you guys were right. CARDS never completed. I was confused because I am calling subscriber.onCompleted(); inside the definition of CARDS (I used the create operator). An I can see that onCompleted is bein called since it is printing in the logs.
I replaced this observable with a list and it is now working fine.